# CSS layout issues with header and content

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, layout

I have created a mockup of the layout I am trying to attempt, but I've run into some issues and I'm trying to figure out how to fulfill all the conditions I have. Here is the stack snippet:

```js
// to check if dynamic <aside> content is working
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
 document.querySelector('main').classList.toggle('expanded');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red; /* to see if <body> shows through */
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav > .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

nav > .wrapper > header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}

main.expanded nav > .wrapper > header  {
  height: 100px;
}

main.expanded section {
  padding-top: 110px;
}

.pull-left {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.pull-right {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}

nav > .wrapper > aside {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 110px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  z-index: 0;
}

section .content {
  position: relative;
  /* to make sure scrolling is correct */
  width: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <div class="pull-left">Navigation</div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" id="toggle">Header Collapse</button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <aside>Dashboard</aside>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class="content">
      <button type="button">Clickable</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Here are the conditions I have to meet:

- The `<header>` and `<aside>` must be `position: fixed` (Already done).
- When the `<header>` height is changed, the content in the `<aside>` must respond by moving lower to stay within view (Already done).
- The content must scroll behind the `<header>` (Already done).
- The content box must be clickable (Needed).
- The `<body>` must not show behind the content box (Needed).
- The content box must be scrollable if overflow is in effect (Already done).
- IE 9+ must be supported (Not sure if I have met this or not).

Please let me know how to meet all these requirements. The HTML does not need to remain the same but please keep the tags semantically correct.

Comment: what do you mean by "the `<body>` must now show behind the content box?

Comment: @MichaelMK sorry that was a typo